# Delete multiple data from several CSV files in one click

Tags: python, csv, batch-file, url, txt

I have more than 500 csv files with identical format - 6 columns (count,height,link,title,titles,width) and with multiple lines. I would like to keep only the "link" column (with all urls) from these >500 csv files. At the end, I would like to convert the final file in .txt with all these data links.

original sample csv file -

```
count,height,link,title,titles,width
1,142,https://url.jpg,,,338
..
...
....
```

to .txt file -

```
https://url.jpg
https://url.jpg
https://url.jpg
https://url.jpg
https://url.jpg
```

Does anyone here have a solution to do that?

Many thanks.

Comment: Try this from the command line: `(for %f in (*.csv) do @for /F "usebackq skip=1 tokens=3 delims=," %a in ("%f") do @echo %a) > result.txt` or convert this to a .BATch file...

Comment: This site is not a free code/script writing service, so you have to try to implement your task your self! Please take the [tour], visit the [help], and read [ask] and [mcve]!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pandas to read your *CSV* files as dataframes, get the *link* column from each file then write the result in a text file. Try this :

```
from os.path import abspath, join
from os import listdir
import pandas as pd


abs_path = abspath(path) # path of your folder

for filename in listdir(abs_path): 
  df = pd.read_csv(join(abs_path, filename), usecols=['link'])
  df.to_csv(filename +'.txt', header=None, index=None, sep=' ', mode='w')
```

**Note** : columns names (at least link column) must be present explicitly in all files.

Comment: Hi sudoer Ali, thank you for your precious help. I haven't knowledge in Python so I try to understand with some research but it's not easy. How can I focus this code on my path directory (where my csvs files are present) to execute your script?

Comment: are your files located directely in your folder (no subfolders) ?

Comment: all my csvs files are located in one folder only (no sub)

Comment: Seems a bit more clear with this listdir but unfortunately I can't install it :( I tried to fix with pip function (macosx) but still can't install this package

Comment: ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement listdir (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for listdir

Comment: you do not need to install os package in order to use listdir, it comes with Python, you just need to install pandas `pip install pandas`

Comment: I installed - pip3 install pandas works. But I still have errors.

Comment: I just post a new answer with the current errors, do you see something wrong? Hopefully it will ending to works :)

Comment: Check it now Hope it 'll work!

Comment: I just modified it again for you ! Welcome.